# PDF:reuse setting page size

Tags: perl, pdf, module

I am using the [PDF::Reuse](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PDF%3a%3aReuse) module in perl and I have my program finished.

I am using a 8.5 x 11  (US letter) template and the finished file comes out as 8.26 x 11.69 (A4 letter).

Is there a command that will change the page size or if I want to make a finished customized size?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
use PDF::Reuse;                    
prFile('myFile.pdf');
prMbox(0, 0, 612, 792);
prText(100, 500, 'Hello World !');
prEnd();
```

prMbox takes units in points. You can use a Google Search to convert from "inches to points".

Answer (score 0):

I don't use PDF::Reuse but the thing you want to grep the documentation for is "mediabox".  Changing it will change the size of the paper.

Comment: Hello Shawn, I did change the mediabox coordinates as you specified and it still comes out as a finished A4 size The PDF template still shows as 8.5 x 11 in the corner as well